# Bind LEFT to goto parent directory in dired mode

Tags: key-bindings

How do I bind the LEFT key to go to parent directory in dired mode?

I tried

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<left>") #'dired-up-directory)
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you tried, but try this:

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<left>") #'dired-up-directory)
```

---

Actually, the source text for your question shows that you tried that, but you need to wrap your source text with three backquotes or else indent it 4 spaces, for it to display correctly.

So if you did actually try the same code shown in my answer then the problem is likely how you tried to evaluate that code (or didn't try). The code itself looks fine, to me.

Comment: It's working now. I had the line inserted correctly, but in the wrong file. Many thanks.

Comment: Please consider deleting your question, in that case. Thx.

Comment: The answer to the question is clearly shown in the answer, so may be of benefit to someone looking for a solution.

Comment: Please [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer then.